# how bundler handle the dependencies and why put eslint thing into `dependencies`?

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint, yarnpkg, pnpm

this is question is basically a variant of `dependencies vs. devDependencies`, I am looking through some source code these days, most of monorepo project will have a `eslint-config` to do lint

what confuses me is that they all put the eslint-plugin into `dependencies` not `devDependencies`
for example, a eslint config package called `eslint-config`, here's `package.json`

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "17.0.0-1",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsonc": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^41.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-yml": "^0.14.0",
    "jsonc-eslint-parser": "^2.1.0",
    "yaml-eslint-parser": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.11.0"
  },
```

we of course use it by `npm i eslint-config -D`, so I wonder if the eslint config get removed after bundled(I think it's 100% get removed), but I want to know the behand philosophy

Comment: You don't install the development dependencies of your dependencies. So if this package is intended to be installed, whether or not as a development dependency, by other packages, the transitive dependencies need to be regular (or peer) dependencies.

Comment: yes, the main thing I want to ensure is why they put eslint thing in `dependencies`

Comment: Then ask the package maintainers, we can't tell you their intentions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file) and [yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-types#toc-devdependencies) documentation, in addition to another answer with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724203/do-devdependencies-affect-bundle-size), `devDependencies` do not impact the bundle size as they are utilized in development mode.

Two related GitHub issue comments discuss the reasoning behind your question, specifically dependencies included at runtime:

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3209#issuecomment-336602578
- https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/770#issuecomment-516056543

Comment: `npm` and `yarn` only use a few lines words to describe it which is far more enough, I like [@ljharb](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3209#issuecomment-336602578)'s answer, put eslint like thing into `dependencies` is really confusing me, and I have tested locally myself, it works well when they are `devDependencies`